# In The Planning Stages of an OEM License, Have a Few Questions

Tags: appexchange, isv, oem

My App will have two major business functions (BF 1, BF 2), each supporting different departments within a customer.

Customer A may want to license BF 1 Only
Customer B may license BF 2 Only
Customer C may license BF 1 & 2

We're considering a tiered licensing model, such that companies who want both functions pay more then those who only license 1 of the functions.

1. Can the OEM org support unique 3rd party integrations for Customer A
   vs B and C? Or, the integration is for All Customers?
2. Can the OEM environments support unique SF to SF integrations, per customer?
3. Please confirm that each of these customers will have the flexibility to create their own new fields, Workflows, Page Layouts, Record Types, Email Services, etc
4. Do the API call limitations aggregate per customer or across ALL Customers? In other word, can customer A hog up all of the API call space and therefore negatively impact all other customers?
5. Does the Security Review cost the same for the OEM license as it does for AppExchange Packages.
6. Can we also list our OEM Package on the AppExchange

Answer (score 0):

I passed your questions on to our ISV team - their responses:

1. Typically, yes, but need more information
2. Typically, yes, but need more information
3. Depends on scope of customization
4. No
5. Yes
6. Yes

The best thing you can do is to sign up at https://partnersignup.salesforce.com/  (this is free, with no obligations - it just puts your details in our system), and chat to one of our ISV team.